# Silverlight Security Issue: Self Signed Certificate

Tags: silverlight, security, silverlight-4.0, internet-explorer-8, cross-domain

I am using silverlight 4 application, in two scenarios.

**Scenario 1: Silverlight and RPC on same machine**

1. Being run hosted on a web page on the file system, silverlight XAP is also on the file system:

   ```
   C:\Silverlight\FSSilverlightApp\bin\Debug\SilverlightApplication2TestPage.html
   ```
2. Connecting to a web site on localhost, being accessed:

   ```
   https://localhost/rpc/someMethod
   ```
3. These are two separate URI's so the browser detects and immediately requests (track via fiddler):

   ```
   https://lcoalhost/clientaccesspolicy.xml
   ```

   sucessfully returns:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <access-policy>
       <cross-domain-access>
           <policy>
             <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
               <domain uri="http://*"/>        
               <domain uri="https://*" /> 
             </allow-from>
             <grant-to>
               <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
             </grant-to>
           </policy>   
      </cross-domain-access> 
   </access-policy>
   ```
4. The application is then able to make the rpc requests (observed via fiddler)

   Everything is fine.  If i change the remote host to the local machine name instead of localhost, that works fine as well.

**Scenario 2: Silverlight on local machine and RPC is remote**

1. In this scenario, I am using a different desktop to access the same RPC server used in scenario 1.
2. Silverlight starts up, and no request to: clientaccesspolicy.xml is made
3. Fiddler shows a ton of https tunnels being established, but no commuinication between my machine and the remote server.

The following security exception is returned:

```cs
System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResultasyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(ObjectsendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.WebExtensions.AsyncGetResponse@1781-1.Invoke(Exception _arg1023)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl.callA@736.Invoke(AsyncParams`1 args)
```

I assume this is an IE configuration issue.  I tried setting the machine in scenario 1, as a trusted site inside of internet explorer and that didn't seem to work...  This must be a self signed or mismatched certificate issue.  Any thoughts?

Using: IE 8 and Windows 7

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Fiddler to sit in between the sliverlight client and the server.  IN order to get that to work properly I needed to export the fiddler certificate (tools\fiddlerOptions\https) and install it locally as the root certificate authority.